# Cordova error while installing ionic to an android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run the ionic cordova run android command and I receive the following error:

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_191
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run android exited with exit code 1.
```

The echo $JAVA_HOME gives /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_191

Not sure what I should check further.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Remove all the Java related packages (Sun, Oracle, OpenJDK, IcedTea plugins, GIJ):

```sh
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e '^java-common' | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

2.Purge config files (careful. This command removed libsgutils2-2 and virtualbox config files too):

```sh
dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{print($2)}' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

3.Remove Java config and cache directory:

```sh
sudo bash -c 'ls -d /home/*/.java' | xargs sudo rm -rf
```

4.Remove manually installed JVMs:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/*
```

5.Remove Java entries, if there is still any, from the alternatives:

```sh
for g in ControlPanel java java_vm javaws jcontrol jexec keytool mozilla-javaplugin.so orbd pack200 policytool rmid rmiregistry servertool tnameserv unpack200 appletviewer apt extcheck HtmlConverter idlj jar jarsigner javac javadoc javah javap jconsole jdb jhat jinfo jmap jps jrunscript jsadebugd jstack jstat jstatd native2ascii rmic schemagen serialver wsgen wsimport xjc xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so; do sudo update-alternatives --remove-all $g; done
```

6.Search for possible remaining Java directories:

```sh
sudo updatedb
sudo locate -b '\pack200'
```

7.Install JAVA-8-SDK

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

8.Open sudo gedit ~/.bashrc and add these lines

```sh
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/yourAndroidStudioPath/Android
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

Try to run your ionic app again :)
Enjoy!

This answer is comming from this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3115#issuecomment-386625912), all the credits is for [@Stradivario](https://github.com/Stradivario)